# Calendar in React not displaying correctly with Tailwind CSS

Tags: reactjs

Description: Hello,

I'm trying to create a calendar in React using Tailwind CSS, but the calendar component is not displaying correctly on the web page. I have checked the console and verified that the rows and columns are generated correctly, but they are stacking vertically on the web page.

Here are the relevant code snippets:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { getMonth } from './util';
import CalendarHeader from './components/CalendarHeader';
import Sidebar from './components/Sidebar';
import Month from './components/Month';

function App() {
  const [currentMonth, setCurrentMonth] = useState(getMonth());
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="h-screen flex flex-columns">
        <CalendarHeader/>
        <div className="flex flex-1">
          <Sidebar/>
          <Month month={currentMonth}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;

import dayjs from 'dayjs';

export function getMonth(month = dayjs().month()){
    const year =dayjs().year()
    const ayinIlkGunu = dayjs(new Date(year, month, 1)).day()
    let currentAySayac = 0 - ayinIlkGunu

    const daysMatrix= new Array(5).fill([]).map(() => {
        return new Array(7).fill(null).map(() => {
            currentAySayac++
            return dayjs(new Date(year, month, currentAySayac))
        })
    })
    return daysMatrix;
}

import React from 'react';
import Day from './Day';

export default function Month({ month }) {
  return (
    <div className="flex-1 grid grid-cols-7 grid-rows-5">
        {month.map((row, i) => (
            <React.Fragment key={i}>
                {row.map((day, idx) => (
                    <Day day={day} key={idx} />   
                ))}
            </React.Fragment>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}

import React from 'react';

export default function Day({ day }) {
  return (
    <div className="bg-gray-200 p-2">
        {day.format()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The **`Month`** component of the calendar is designed to have a grid structure with 7 columns and 5 rows. However, on the web page, the calendar is stacking vertically.

I'm using Tailwind CSS for styling, and I have added the **`bg-gray-200 p-2`** classes to the **`Day`** component to style each day element.

How can I resolve this issue? Is there any error or missing piece in the provided code? I'm looking forward to your assistance.

### Thank you!

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-shannon-pjwsp4?file=/src/util.js

Comment: Hi, You didn't use any configuration to install it, while using Tailwind CSS `tailwind.config.css`, `postcss.config.css`, installing `autoprefixer`..., etc. everything you needed to styling your calendar. For more information, you can read this [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation)

Comment: I tried my best to set it up correctly, but I will double-check it again. Thank you.

Comment: @Sks7 you didnot install tailwindcss in your project, kindly follow all the steps [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/using-postcss)

Comment: "I have resolved the issue. Thank you for your attention to the small mistake I made while installing Tailwind."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really hard to make Tailwind work in the CodeSandBox it seems... You were missing to import the css in the index.js:

**Index.js**

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

import "./styles.css"; //  Import here

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

And create this file on root, beside package.json:

**tailwind.config.js**

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {}
  },
  plugins: []
};
```

In the sandbox it's not gonna work, but if you export to ZIP and run local it will:

https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-bash-lqdd3w?file=/src/index.js

[image]